# Android: Read line from text file ending early of asset

Tags: java, android, file

I'm reading a text file with over thousands of lines of data in it on Android. For each line I want to read, split it apart, save it into a class and add that class to an arraylist. This is my code currently:

```
try {
    InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("assets.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // use line variable
        String[] assetLineSplit = line.split("\\t");

        //Create object of assets
        assetObjectClass assetObjects = new assetObjectClass();

        assetObjects.setAssetNumber(assetLineSplit[0]);
        assetObjects.setDepArea(assetLineSplit[2]);

        assetCompleteList.add(assetObjects); //Array list

        Log.i("test", assetObjects.getAssetNumber());
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TEST", String.valueOf(e));
    }
```

Of which I've obtained from around the place. Now things seem to be working fine in terms of setting the objects, but I only seem to get to 470, and then it terminates as if its finished when its not.

I've checked line 470ish, and theres no blank lines or anything like that compared to the others so I don't know why at this arbitrary amount it stops at or whether it has to do with something else?

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Is an exception thrown to cause it to finish, or is readLine() returning null?

Comment: Didn't think to check that, cheers, I checked now, there is an exception being thrown as it go's into my catch statement. It says "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=25; index=25"  although I'm still not sure what that means? I do know I'm definitely going further then 25 elements?

Comment: Hi thats right Gosu, I get about 470 loops in and then it stops, I see that it go's into the catch statement now although still not entirely sure why?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace? Which line is throwing that error?

Comment: @JohnMcKenzie Initially I thought it was due to the 'line limit' of your console, but since u have an error/exception, maybe you could show us what is it?

Comment: @JohnMcKenzie at the exception, do this instead: `e.printStackTrace();` and show us the stack trace

Comment: If a line in the file does not have enough tab characters it will crash when you try and access the split array assetLineSplit[2].

Comment: Thanks Gosu and BrentM, you're both right, it was the line assetLineSplit[2] thats doing it, I removed it and it ran through just fine now. I added a second try catch purely for that line, so now it loops through everything and just quits the second try catch instead of the first and keeps going perfectly. 
If either of you want to copy and paste the answer below I will be more then happy to accept it as the correct answer and all that jazz. Thanks a lot guys I really appreciate it!!